# Excel VBA-looking to match similar numbers in a more efficient way

Tags: vba, excel

I have two hardware devices that record data and I need to sync the times recorded by each so the data matches on both devices.

The times are close but not always identical: I record data every 0.2 seconds, but sometimes one device will have a slightly larger or smaller gap.

Currently, I import the times from L unit and R unit into excel, then round the times to the nearest 0.1 sec. That way, the times either match exactly or are off by 0.1 sec (which is close enough for my purposes).

I wrote a VBA script (below) to paste the data from the R unit into the L unit. It works fine, but it is too slow for the amount of data I am dealing with (25,000+ rows)

I hoping someone can examine the code and suggest a faster way to do the same thing.

```
Sub NewTimesComparisonLoop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LBottomRow As Long
Dim RBottomRow As Long

Dim LSheet As Worksheet
Dim Rsheet As Worksheet
Dim LStartCell As Range
Dim RStartcell As Range

Dim Li As Long
Dim Ri As Long

Set LSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Rsheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'find the last row of times in column b

Set LStartCell = Range("B1")
LBottomRow = LSheet.Cells(LSheet.Rows.Count, LStartCell.Column).End(xlUp).row

Set RStartcell = Range("B1")
RBottomRow = Rsheet.Cells(Rsheet.Rows.Count, RStartcell.Column).End(xlUp).row

'get data set of sheet1, column B
'LSheet.Range(StartCell, LSheet.Cells(BottomRow, 2)).Select

'loop through each R value, comparing against a loop of L values
'if they match, or if R is under by 0.1 sec, copy the R values into columns j through P

For Ri = 1 To RBottomRow
    For Li = 1 To LBottomRow

        If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 2).Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 10).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 3).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 11).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 4).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 12).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 5).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 13).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 6).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 14).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 7).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 15).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 8).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 16).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 9).Value
        ElseIf Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 2).Value + 0.1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 2).Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 10).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 3).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 11).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 4).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 12).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 5).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 13).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 6).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 14).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 7).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 15).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 8).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 16).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 9).Value
        End If
    Next Li
Next Ri

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a collection when matching values.  Here I use a Scripting.Dictionary.

```
Sub NewTimesComparisonLoop()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cell As Range, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cell In .Range("B1", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then dict.Add cell.Value, cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 7).Value
        Next
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("B1", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 7).Value = dict(cell.Value)
            ElseIf dict.Exists(cell.Value + 0.1) Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 7).Value = dict(cell.Value + 0.1)
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant - deleted my answer in shame :D

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Excelosaurus lol.thanks. hmm....I should have used an ElseIf statement.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this type of post belongs in [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

But I don't know how to vote to migrate it there, so here's what should be a significantly smaller code... how it compares in regards to execution time is a little up in the air, but it ought to be faster as well.

Replace this:

```
For Ri = 1 To RBottomRow
    For Li = 1 To LBottomRow

        If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 2).Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 10).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 3).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 11).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 4).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 12).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 5).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 13).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 6).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 14).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 7).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 15).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 8).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 16).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 9).Value
        ElseIf Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 2).Value + 0.1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 2).Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 10).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 3).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 11).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 4).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 12).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 5).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 13).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 6).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 14).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 7).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 15).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 8).Value
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 16).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 9).Value
        End If
    Next Li
Next Ri
```

With this:

```
For Ri = 1 To RBottomRow
    For Li = 1 To LBottomRow
        If ("Sheet2").Cells(Ri, 2).Value - Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Li, 2).Value <= 0.1 Then _ 
          Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & Li & ":P" & Li).Value = _
          ("Sheet2").Range("C" & Ri & ":I" & Ri).Value
    Next Li
Next Ri
```

Comment: Thanks. I know the value transfer coding could be shortened, but first I wanted to deal with the slowness of the double for-next loops. This will help in several other places.